# SQL SERVER converting dates with multiple formats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a varchar column with dates like this:

```
1. 01-JUN-13
2. 01/23/12
3. 01.13.13
4. 01-13-13
5. 13-01-13
```

Is it possible to convert all of them to single format?  I have tried a lot of converts/casts usually resulting in 
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

or nothing happening.

Comment: It seems that 4 and 5 are non deterministic.  How do we know what "02-03-13" is?  It could be february 3rd or march 2nd.

Comment: _Please_ tell me the purpose here is to change this into a DATETIME column, rather than varchar? That's what you should be doing.

Comment: @BillGregg Or March 13, 2002.

Comment: Yes that is the purpose, to cast/convert all and send to a new table with a datetime column.  I did not set this table up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to convert all varchar value to a date, because it is an ambiguous request..

Given this value: 02/03/2011 4:15:22 PM +0500

How will i know if it's 2 of March or 3 of February?

**Edit:**
Assuming you ignore this case, you will need to cast each format using the relevant conversion  method, you can find many posts about this, like those:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: I'll be using a where clause to identify mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy based on another column.  I am more interested if it is possible if you ignore this instance.

Comment: Assuming you have the format in another column, YES it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I was young and naive thinking SQL Server would have a catch all function for dates and evaluate one by one.

I did find a python package that is useful.  Here is the code I used, it's not perfect but it evaluates one at a time to figure out the dateformat

```
import pypyodbc
from dateutil import parser



def load_table(connection,type):
    curPull = connection.cursor()

    # Pull rows
    if type == "diff":
        updateStatement = ("UPDATE tmp_date SET convertedDateTime = ? WHERE id = ?")
        curPull.execute("select id,dateNeeded,convertedDateTime from tmp_date where convertedDateTime IS NULL")
        result_set = curPull.fetchall()
        for row in result_set:
            vrowid = row[0]
            vdateNeeded = row[1]
            vconvertedDateTime = row[2]

            vparsedDate = parser.parse(vdateNeeded)
            curPull.execute(updateStatement, (vparsedDate,vrowid))
    connection.commit() 

def main():
    serverIn = ""
    databaseIn = ""
    username = ""
    password = ""
    conString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=%s;Database=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;" % (serverIn, databaseIn, username, password)
    connection = pypyodbc.connect(conString)


    load_table(connection,"diff")
    connection.close()


main()
```